# Move NDR messages to a folder not in the inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to move NDR messages to a folder which is not in the inbox.

I found working code online which moves the NDRs but not where I want it. I assume that the problem is with the path:

```vb
Set Folders = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
Set Folder = Folders.Item("NDR")
```

How can I move the NDRs to the "nem_kezbesitheto" subfolder in "x_spam"?

Outlook folder structure
[image]

```vb
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error Resume Next

    If UCase(Item.MessageClass) = "REPORT.IPM.NOTE.NDR" Then
        Set Folders = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
        Set Folder = Folders.Item("NDR")
        If Folder Is Nothing Then
            Folder = Folders.Add("NDR")
        End If
        Item.Move Folder
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason to resort to VBA for this. Setup a rule to automatically move emails to a specified sub folder

Comment: However you haven't initialised variables `Dim Folders As Outlook.MAPIFolder` and something like `Set Folders = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("NDR")`

Comment: Outlook rules can't handle NDR messages unfortunately

Comment: Avoid `On Error Resume Next`. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling#On_Error_Resume_Next.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the target folder is located in a separate store. Use the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the `Store` objects in the current profile. For example:

```
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
     EnumerateFolders oRoot 
 Next 
 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub EnumerateFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder)
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders 
 Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim foldercount As Integer 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 
 Set folders = oFolder.folders 
 foldercount = folders.Count 
 'Check if there are any folders below oFolder 
 
 If foldercount Then 
   For Each Folder In folders
     Debug.Print (Folder.FolderPath) 
 
     EnumerateFolders Folder 
 
   Next 
 End If
End Sub
```

So, instead of using the following line of code:

```
Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
```

You will have to use the following one:

```
Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
```

Where the `store` object represents the target store. You will have to find it using the `Stores` collection returned from the corresponding property of the `Namespace` class.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate the folder tree from the top level `Session` to "nem_kezbesitheto".

It looks like x_spam is at the mailbox level. If not adjust to step from `Session` to mailbox to folder to folder to folder, one at a time.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Private WithEvents Items As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim x_spamMailbox As folder
    Dim myFolder As folder
    
    If UCase(Item.MessageClass) = "REPORT.IPM.NOTE.NDR" Then
    
        'Navigate the folder tree
        
        ' Assuming x_spam is at the mailbox level
        Set x_spamMailbox = Session.folders("x_spam")

        ' Step from mailbox to folder (to folder to folder as needed)
        Set myFolder = x_spamMailbox.folders("nem_kezbesitheto")

        Item.Move myFolder
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```